# Why is known what is a byte in a bytestream?

Tags: c++, qt, byte

If I have a wav-file, and its header starts this way:

```
5249 4646
```

Then, if I read it in somehow like (stream is a QByteStream)

```
char riff[4] // 4 byte
stream.readRawData(riff,4); // reads 4 bytes into the char riff
```

Why is known that 4 bytes mean 5249 4646? One byte 52, the next 49, and so on.
If it was a text .txt-file, every single visible character would be a byte, not every two. What we see, is it the same the stream is seing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
5249 4646
```

is actually 4 bytes expressed as hex. You might write them like this:

```
52 49 46 46
```

which is more byte oriented.

Now, ASCII code for R is 0x52. For I it is 0x49. And for F it is 0x46.

The specification for these files mandates that the first 4 bytes of the file is the header, and that header must be the 4 bytes that we have picked apart above. A good reason for picking these 4 bytes is that when you look at the file in a hex editor, the hex editor will attempt to interpret the bytes as ASCII if it can and so you can see by simple inspection that the first 4 bytes interpreted as ASCII are RIFF and then you know, in all likelihood, what kind of file it is.

For example, here's a sample WAV file as viewed in a hex editor:

[image]

Comment: I already know that since I also opened a wave file. But the stream, is it seeing some 001111011101011, counts each 8 bits and says: This is a byte. But how could he. What is the raw data. Perhaps the numbers 5249 4646 are not hex, but deci, and would look other in binary. Or if the source is really binary, it would not look like 5249 4646 in deci. Do you know what I mean? Can't explain it well.

Comment: No. I have no idea what you mean. `52494646` is hex.

Comment: I suppose you are asking how anyone can tell whether a stream of bits represents a byte, word, dword or something else. Well, you can't without more knowledge. Files and memory are byte oriented. So a file is a stream of bytes. It's up to the application to know how to interpret those bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Those 4 bytes are not known. You're just reading 4 bytes, that's it. A single byte has a value between 0 and 255.